# How will baking chicken at a high heat differ from a lower heat?

Tags: temperature, chicken-breast

I want to fix my daughter's favorite foods for her birthday -- chicken and fries -- but don't want to actually deep-fry anything.  (Don't have a deep-fryer, for one thing.) I have found a couple of highly-rated recipes for baked "fries"  and pan-fried then baked chicken breasts.  The only problem is that the fries call for a 450-degree oven and the chicken calls for 375.  I only have one oven, so I am trying to figure out the best way to cook both and have them ready at the same time. I thought about baking the fries first, then the chicken and putting the fries back in to re-heat for the last 5-10 minutes.  I don't want soggy fries, though, and am not sure this way is best.  I also don't want dried out chicken. although the pan-fry then bake method promises that it will be tender and juicy.  Ideal would be to find a way to cook them at the same time, as I will be doing this after getting home from work. I do have a convect-bake setting on my oven, if that makes any difference.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you be open at all to buying additional kitchen equipment, such as an Air Fryer?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to cook chicken at 450 degrees. I have a recipe that cooks 1/2 inch thick chicken cutlets at 500 degrees for 8 minutes , so at 450 I would cook them for 10-12 minutes, or 15-20 for full-thickness chicken breast. This high-heat method can actually keep your chicken moister than a lower-heat method, and will work with your French fries, so maybe find a recipe that cooks at 450 degrees. There are many available if you google "chicken breast 450."

Answer (score 0):

You will have no problem cooking the chicken at 450F (232C), as another answer suggests.  However, you will get the best results if you simply use a thermometer to monitor the internal temperature of your chicken.  Just remove it when the temperature is 10-15 degrees below your target temperature.  Let it rest about 10 minutes, and the carry-over cooking be enough to finish the job.

Answer (score -1):

The main issue with high temperature is that chicken can end up being dry, i.e. the worst kind of chicken possible. To mitigate it before putting it in the oven to roast, quickly fry it on the pan to form nice crust on the outside. This crust will prevent juices from escaping too easily.

Comment: Based on what I know that's not quite correct - searing meat doesn't prevent juices from escaping, although I've heard that from several people. If you think of a resting steak, you can imagine why.